# Moodle notifications are not working in the mobile (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, cordova, moodle

iPhone notification plugin is not working using Moodle mobile application.Can any help me from this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Is there an error message? Do you have some code you have tried?

Comment: In moodle site they are using airnotifier plugin for receiving notifications in mobile app.They enabled the plugin.When i'm running the moodle mobile app in iPhone i'm not receiving any notifications from the moodle site.Where i have to start for this,can u please help me for this.Thanks in advance

Comment: if this isn't directly related to programming it might get a better response some where else http://webapps.stackexchange.com/ :)

Comment: I can't understand what you are saying.

Comment: var notificationsFilter = MM.db.where("notifications", {siteid: MM.config.current_site.id}) In this condition i'm getting null.